# Persist checkbox values on postback in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, http-post

Model:

```
  public class UserViewModel
    {       
        public UserDetail user { get; set; }
        public List<int> SelectedRoles { get; set; }     
    }
```

HttpGet Action:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        ViewBag.Roles = list of roles (List<Roles>)
        return View();
   }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{      

    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Roles)
    {

      <input id="SelectedRoles" name="SelectedRoles" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" >         
      @item.Name
    } 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  
}
```

HttpPost Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel model, FormCollection form)
  {
     foreach (int roleId in model.SelectedRoles)
     {

         Here I am getting IDs of SelectedRoles as roleId
     }
  }
```

On HttpPost I want to persist checkbox values as I have selected. How to do it in MVC3?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the checkboxes are bound to a property on the ViewBag. You have to re-assign the roles on the ViewBag in the post action, so that the UI can be rebound when the view is rendered after the post action has executed.
The viewbag will not persist between different view renderings, so it must be reset